# Adding 2 styles to the same line in the TOC

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I am creating a song book and would like to create a Table Of Contents.
The layout in the text looks like this:

Angie <-- formatted with style "SongTitle"

```
By The Rolling Stones (1973) <-- formatted with style "Performer"
```

As I want to keep the layout on the pages like this, the TOC creates the entries like this:

Angie..............................5

By The Rolling Stones (1973).......5

Whatever I try, I can't seem to get them combined on the first line, so that it would look like this:

Angie By The Rolling Stones (1973)..............5

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? My knowledge of Word seems to be insufficient..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to put both lines in a single paragraph with the Paragraph style that you want to use in the Table of Contents, and use a different Character style to format the text of the second line.

For example, you create a Paragraph Style called Song Title with the font characteristics you need for the Title line ("Angie") and the paragraph line spacing that you need between the title line and the performer line.

Then you create a Character Style called Performer with the font characteristics that you need for " By The Rolling Stones"

Then type

```
Angie<shift-enter>
 By The Rolling Stones<enter>
```

Format the entire paragraph with, "Song Title".

Select `By the Rolling Stones` and format it with the "Performer" style.

Then build a ToC using the "Song Title" style. You may find that the ToC uses different character styling for the Title and the Performer, but until you can see whether this is going to work for you, I think that is a secondary issue.

There are variations on this approach, e.g. you could use a Paragraph style called "Song Details" for the paragraph, then one Character style for the Song Title and another for the Performer.

Another approach would be to keep your existing Styles, then insert a nested field code like this in the next paragraph under the Performer:

{ TC \l 1 "{ STYLEREF "Song Title" } { STYLEREF "Performer " }" }

Then build the ToC using the "Table Entry Fields" option in the ToC Options.

*Each* pair of { } needs to be inserted using the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word. Word will omit the space att he begining of your Performer line so you have to add it manually between the two STYLEREF fields. You will also have to update all these fields (ctrl-A then F9, probably twice, before the ToC entries are up-to-date.

The former approach seems to be a lot simpler to me but there may be reasons to use the latter.

Comment: Hi Yokki,Many thanks for your reply, will check that out as soon as I can! Sorry for the delay in reply, been quite busy with all the Corona-stuff, but now technically unemployed for 3 weeks, so I will get my chance to test your solution. Will keep you posted!

Comment: @Hunicrem yes, strange times. Let me know...